Настройка Webhook для двух ботов Telegram Node JS
Два бота Telegram, одинаковая основа, разные базы данных JSON, не получается поставить на бесплатный Webhook, пробовал простым polling, но два одновременно не получилось запустить, выдает ошибку 409:
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const fuzzball = require('fuzzball'); // Библиотека погрешности 
const data = require('./questions_and_answers.json'); // JSON файл

const token = 'xxxxxxx';

const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

bot.onText(/\/start/, (msg) => {
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Привет! Я бот, который может отвечать на ваши вопросы. Тема - VR.");
});

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  const userQuestion = msg.text.toLowerCase();
  let bestMatch, bestRatio = 0;

  for (const question of data) {
      const ratio = fuzzball.ratio(userQuestion, question.question.toLowerCase());
      if (ratio > bestRatio) {
          bestMatch = question;
          bestRatio = ratio;
      }
  }
//отправка ответа с учетом погрешности
  if (bestRatio > 65) { //порог погрешности 
      const answer = Array.isArray(bestMatch.answer) ? bestMatch.answer.join(", ") : bestMatch.answer;
      bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `Вы имели в виду: ${bestMatch.question}? \n\n Ответ:\n ${answer}`);
  } else {
      bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Извините, я не знаю ответа на этот вопрос.");
  }
});

bot.on("polling_error", console.log);


polling работает только для бота запущенного в единственном экземпляре
